# How to replace link_directories with enviroment variables or -D<command> with cmake in windows, thanks

Tags: c++, cmake

I have tried with Path, but it didn't work. it says:
`ld.lld: error: unable to find library -lfoo`
What can i do?

Comment: You probably should not do what you ask however we would need to see your CMakeLists.txt for help with the proper solution. Instead you probably want to use find_package() or find_library()

Comment: why would do you need to do this replacement? Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Tell us the actual problem you're trying to solve here

Comment: [LIBRARY_PATH](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html) - `The value of LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated list of directories, much like PATH...Linking using GCC also uses these directories when searching for ordinary libraries for the -l option (but directories specified with -L come first).`

Comment: The use of `-l<libname>` is almost certainly wrong. Assuming you're using MSVC, the flags are differnet, so just use the functionality provided by cmake that applies the appropriate flags given the library name and just specify `foo` as library to link in `target_link_libraries`. Any link directory may be added using `target_link_directories`; just refer to the cache variable via usual means (`${VAR_NAME}` or `$CACHE{VAR_NAME}` depending on the desired behaviour) or do the same for the environment variable `$ENV{VAR_NAME}`.

Comment: If there's a cmake configuration script or find script for the given package, the use of this functionality is much prefered though and even without this a custom version could be created providing an imported target...

Comment: ```link_directories(./libs)

add_library(hello SHARED hello.cpp hello.h)

target_link_libraries(hello foo)```

Comment: I just want to ellipsis the link_directories line, even it may be harder